# Open infoWindow inner agm-marker-cluster

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3

I have to open the infoWindow inner agm-marker-cluster, but I receive this error:

```
Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

in this line

```
return _this._markerManager.getNativeMarker(infoWindow.hostMarker).then(function (marker)
```

I create a Plunker [here](https://embed.plnkr.co/a0J7prrfXtJe9dRAyEZi/).

Answer (score 1):

I found there is a closed issue at github project:

https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps/issues/1190

It has been resolved but not yet released on npm.

I compiled source code from repository and now it works.